# Not getting the jquery work in jsp page using extremecomponent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

In the JSP page I am applying the jQuery using this :

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.even').children('td,th').css("background-color", "blue");
  });
```

which ofcourse is not working.

But the same page when getting rendered in the Browser and I open the javascript console and put this expression

```
$('.even').children('td,th').css("background-color", "blue");
```

I get the desired effect in both the Chrome and IE.

How to get it work consistently?

Comment: "which ofcourse is not working" — Why of course? It looks alright. What does the JavaScript console say? What do you get if you console.log $('.even') or $('.even').children('td,th')?

Comment: Just see `$('.even')` is that what you know.

Comment: I was joking dude, it looks good and yet its not working that's what has forced me to be here and asking for help from you :). The console.log($('.even')) gives LOG: [object Object] in IE and Array of objects in Chrome.

Comment: @Jai Not getting what are you suggesting.

Comment: I think more than jQuery it has got something to do with extremecomponents.

Comment: @JohnDoe see jquery works in browser. so your dom has to be loaded before any execution and you are doing it properly as i see. so the issue might be either your element has been changed or it might processed after page load.